# ipdb show color code instead of color

Tags: python, ipython, ipdb

Use `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` to insert breakpoint.
Color is fine when first hit the breakpoint, but it shows color code instead of true color when hit the BP the second time (by press `c`) and so on.

```
    ←[1;32m     72 ←[1;33m        ←[1;32mimport←[0m ←[0mipdb←[0m←[1;33m;←[0m ←[0mipdb←[0m←[1;33m.←[0m←[0mset_trace←[0m←[1;33m(←[0m←[1;33m)←[0m  ←[1;31m# XXX BREAKPO
    INT←[0m←[1;33m←[0m←[0m
```

It is in windows 7, python 2.7 and 2.6 have the same issue. I think one work around method is using nocolor scheme (how to get nocolor scheme?) And how to fix this issue with color scheme available? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, running in Windows native command prompt with pyreadline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a known issue when using ipdb for Windows: https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb/issues/31

Apparently, this ticket is still open.

There is a quickfix from a guy that solves the problem:

> OK ... I commented out line ipdb/**main**.py:43 which sets io.stdout
>   and sys.stdout. Then I added a "pass" statement.
>
> This now seems to work for me on windows.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean the line `# io.stdout = sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__`? In my case, it is at line 60 in `ipdb/__main__.py`. It works for me as well.

Comment: Probably you are using a new version of ipdb. But that is it!

Comment: I installed `ipdb` via `easy_install`, in order to apply this fix do I have to install from source?

Comment: Ok I uninstalled via `pip uninstall ipdb`, then downloaded from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb, unzipped, edited the file on line 60 as mentioned here, then ran `setup.py install`. Now it's working

Comment: This issue has hopefully being fixed in [ipdb 0.8.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb/0.8.1).